# Screen orientation information generated by Javascript won't display in Android emulator

Tags: javascript, android, screen, orientation

I'm learning Android development using *Pro Android Web Apps* (Apress, Auths: Damon Oehlman & Sebastien Blanc). I ran into a snag in the second chapter (not a good sign if I'm having trouble already). I couldn't find any help from the Apress site on the book, so I'm hoping you guys can help me out here.

The chapter has me build an html, css, and js file that are supposed to detect and display the orientation of the device as the user rotates it (rotates the device, that is :) ).

When I run the code in an Android emulator running on my local WAMP server, the page displays ok (I don't think the css is quite right, but that's no big deal), but the data regarding the orientation isn't being displayed at all. I made sure the link to the js file is correct, and I've even downloaded all three files from the Apress site to see if it's something in my code, but those won't work either. The book's code is written for v2.1.

I have posted the code for the three files [here](http://www.eventidewebdesign.com/public/android/). Since I'm working through the book using a local WAMP server, I don't really know how to make it easier for someone to take the files and test them his/herself. Sorry.

I really hope someone can take a look at the code and help me out. I'd **really** appreciate it, so I can continue on working through the book!

Thanks!

[Edit]
I just figured out how to change the orientation in the emulator and the display does rotate, but again, the output that the js is supposed to generate isn't displaying after the bulleted items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help too much but recommend that you use an actual device for things like this. If you still wish to use the emulator, make sure you choose Android 2.1 for the OS. You can also debug using the equivalent of `System.out.println` by using `Log.d("tagname","line to be displayed");` which will display lines onto DDMS (which if you're using Eclipse can be seen by selecting `Window -> View Perspective -> Other -> DDMS` which will really help you debug this problem more!

Comment: I'd love to test with an actual device, but I'm going through this book in anticipation of a project I have in mind and I don't, unfortunately, have an Android of my own (and I really can't afford one at the moment either - but that's my own problem!).

I'll try the debugging method you mentioned this evening.

Comment: I'm using Aptana Studio 3 and there is no "DDMS" listed in any of the Perspective folders. Does anyone know of an equivalent in my version of Eclipse?

Comment: And could someone provide an explanation of Log.d. I checked it out at the Android Development site, but I really didn't understand it too well. By "tagname", does that mean an HTML tag? What is "line to be displayed"? Is that the text that will be displayed in the log (such as "value of variable a is: 5")?

Comment: Oh, I would advise you use Eclipse since it's really the standard for making Android applications (Google references it in their developer docs all the time). Log is basically the equivalent of the console window. You can print out error messages (Log.e), debug messages (Log.d), information messages (Log.i) and then specify the tag name (some arbitary identifier used for searching, can be anything) and the message to output just like using the console window. Lots of apps use Log, so tags are designed to make filtering easier.

Comment: Aptana is based on Eclipse. Apparently they've changed some stuff around, though! Thanks for explaining Log some more.